# Check if MongoDB mutation will succeed without actually executing it

Tags: mongodb

I wonder how/if a MongoDB mutation can be simulated. By "simulated" I mean performing an insert, update or delete action without actually executing it. For example, I'd like to test if the uniqueness index will throw when trying to insert a duplicated value. I search for similar functionality to Ethereum estimate gas action which will throw on an invalid transaction before the transaction is actually sent to the network.

Comment: There isn't a way to do a "dry run" for an insert, update, or delete in mongodb. But, if you're only concerned about a duplicate value, couldn't you just make a query to see if something already exists?

Comment: @kmdreko I need to hit index constraints by not modifying the collection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using MongoDB 4.0 or newer, you can use [transactions](https://www.mongodb.com/transactions) to simulate a dry run. Something like:

```
conn = pymongo.MongoClient()

with conn.start_session() as s:
    s.start_transaction()
    conn.test.test.insert_one({'_id':1}, session=s)
    conn.test.test.delete_one({'_id':2}, session=s)

    if ...dry run condition...:
        s.abort_transaction()
    else:
        s.commit_transaction()
```

You can `abort_transaction()` for your dry run, or commit otherwise, like in a typical SQL style transaction. Similarly, a transaction will auto abort if it encounters any error.

Note that transactions require a replica set and MongoDB >= 4.0 to function. See the [manual page on transactions](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/transactions/) for more details.

Comment: That's what I had in mind. And this will hit indexes before `commit_transaction`?

Comment: If you try to insert a duplicate `_id` it will immediately abort the transaction, so yes I believe it does